# nginx : how to split error directive. error_page away from default.conf with same virtual host

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, alpine-linux, custom-error-pages

i am working on nginx:1.21-alpine image , i want to create a custom error pages and everything is going well but i want to make the

```
error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 421 422 423 424 425 426 428 429 431 451 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 510 511 /error.html;
location = /error.html {
    ssi on;
    internal;
    auth_basic off;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
```

away from the default.conf as another department will add it

but i am working in same virtual host

so i used include
in nginx.conf

```
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*;
```

and i put it without server in error.conf file

i got this

"location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/error.conf:2

so i add it into server block , but default.conf overwrite it , after changing error.conf to a.conf it overwrites default.conf ,

what can i do to make them work together completing each others
as the configurations in deafault.conf and only error directive in error.conf